# How to overwrite model update method

Tags: django, django-models

I can simply overwrite the save save method like so

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Do something
        super(Goal, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        # Do something else
```

How come i can't overwrite the update method in the same way? It doesn't run any of my custom code when updating an object.

```
def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Do something
        super(Goal, self).update(*args, **kwargs)
        # Do something else
```

Comment: A model is updated with the `save` method as well, not with an `update` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

save method is what Django uses for updating models. the builtin save() method offers one of the most common operations for Django models: to save (i.e. create or update)

You can override Update method of Django queryset

```
super(GoalQuerySet,self).update(*args, **kwargs)
```